# Secure way for registering .NET 4.5 on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine with IIS 7.5. In IIS there is an  running asp.net mvc 3 app targeting .NET 4.0 framework. I need to publish an asp.net mvc 5 EF 6 targeting .NET 4.5 framework.

I've already installed .NET 4.5. Now I have to register .NET 4.5 in IIS, my question is: Does aspnet_regiis command crash running apps on IIS? Is it required to restart the server or the site?

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -?`

Comment: Questions about server administration are best directed to our [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have firstly installed .NET 4.0, and registered it on IIS 7.5. Then I don't think you need to run aspnet_regiis.exe after installing .NET 4.5.

Comment: thanks Lex Li. I'll try to deploy my app without re-register .net 4.5